# Heap dump when OutOfMemory is due to "unable to create new native thread"

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-dump

We recently got an OutOfMemory is due to "unable to create new native thread" on our Tomcat servers. We know what the issue is - there was a bug that spawned too many Threads beyond what the [ulimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread) on the box allowed.

What intrigues me is that, when this happened the JVM didn't dump the heap. I checked that is behavior was consistent in Java 6 and 8.

I wrote some quick Groovy PoCs to prove this behavior. So while I have used groovy here the behavior is consistent with my Servlet application (just easier for me to share a working model of the problem).

Dumps the Heap - `TraditionalOOM.groovy`:

```
byte[] b = new byte[1000000000]
```

Does **NOT** dump the heap - `ManyThreads.groovy`:

```
int MAX = 5000;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            sleep(1000);
        }
    }.start();
}

Thread.activeCount();
```

The Java Options relevant to this issue (IMHO) are the following 2:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/somewhere
```

I wanted to know:

- Why does the JVM not dump the heap during an OOM (even dumping the thread dump would be helpful)?
- Is the answer the obvious one, that JVM doesn't have a thread to perform the dump?

---

**Update**

I got my answer - seems like this is the expected behavior and Oracle (or Sun) had rejected this behavior as a defect - http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=74ee28dae329645479a51f6c78f2?bug_id=6784422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer - seems like this is the expected behavior and Oracle (or Sun) had rejected this behavior as a defect -

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=74ee28dae329645479a51f6c78f2?bug_id=6784422

The link states "Allocation of a native thread is not from the heap or the permanent generation - hence failure to allocate one does not result in a heap dump. (There would be little point in dumping the heap as that is not what was exhausted.)"

Which I don't completely agree with, since the heap dump also has a wealth of info on the threads. The JVM should at least dump the thread dump if that is Oracle's (or then Sun's) position.

Comment: I have never done it with the Oracle/Sun JVM, but I know that it's possible to configure the IBM JVM to drop either javacore or heap dumps on fairly arbitrary conditions like particular exceptions

Comment: That's interesting, mind sharing the option you use with the IBM VM? I may be able to look for something on the lines for Oracle VM. Thanks.