# Executor Service Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a REST Webservices processing its request by getting result from the legacy system via socket calling.

Since there are 4 sockets available, I setup a `Executorservice` with no of 4 threads to queue for such connections. The service initially runs ok, but performance starts to degrade after a  while; which I use jconsole and found that it is creating > 3000 threads and finally ended with  the  following errors:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with
path [/DCardServices] threw exception [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
unable to create new native thread] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

Questions:

1. Why am I getting so many threads created?
2. Do I have to shutdown the Executorservice in this case?? How as I am in a Web service environment.

Following is a snippet of my code.

```
ExecutorService spool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.valueOf(GlobalUtils.getAppProp().getString("socketPoolSize")).intValue());  
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

public Response queforTdmProcess(JSSigData jsData) {
    return sndWSResponse(jsData.processCardResp1(executorService.submit(new TdmSocketRequest(jsData,socketQueue, spool)).get()));
}

public class TdmSocketRequest implements Callable<String>  {
    Socket s = getSocketFromPool();
    /* connection to socket and get data */
    retSocketToPool(s);
}


public Socket getSocketFromPool() {
    try {
        conSocketConsumer sckconsumer = new conSocketConsumer(getSocketQueue());
        Future<Socket> future = getSpool().submit(sckconsumer); 
        Socket s = future.get();
        System.out.print("Getting socket " +  s.getLocalPort() + " from the pool"  + "\n");

            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

public void retSocketToPool(Socket s) {
        conSocketProducer sckProducer = new conSocketProducer(getSocketQueue(),s);
        System.out.print("Returning socket " +  s.getLocalPort() + " to the pool" + "\n" );
        getSpool().submit(sckProducer);
    }
}
```

Thanks a great deal in advance for any suggestions and help!

Comment: Please improve the code-formatting in your question

Answer (score 0):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.valueOf(GlobalUtils.getAppProp().getString("socketPoolSize")).intValue());`

That line causes the JVM to create `Integer.valueOf(GlobalUtils.getAppProp().getString("socketPoolSize")).intValue()` threads. Socket pools tend to represent how many connections it can create and are usually in the 2000-3000 range. You should not be creating thread pools of that size.

Looking at the rest of your code I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with that pool. You create sockets in the new threads but then block to retrieve those sockets on the original thread. I suggest you remove all the threading you've added because at the moment it does nothing but add more threads.

Lastly when working with asynchronous processing it is almost always a bad idea to use `Future.get()` since that negates any benefit from multithreading. Having to use it indicates you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why am I getting so many threads created?

```
ExecutorService spool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.valueOf(
GlobalUtils.getAppProp().getString("socketPoolSize")).intValue());
```

Currently you are creating those many threads and you should not require those many threads.

Check the value of `socketPoolSize` in your properties and that will answer your query. Check maximum number of processes allowed in your server and that value should be greater than `socketPoolSize`

Have a look at below question:

["java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

> 2. Do I have to shutdown the Executorservice in this case?? How as I am in a Web service environment.

Yes. You have to shutdown ExecutorService irrespective of your environment. Refer to below SE question:

[How to forcefully shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-forcefully-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)