# Spark Streaming on YARN - There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

This is a Spark Streaming application running on YARN cluster mode which produces messages in three Kafka Brokers.

As soon as it reaches 150K open files it fails:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed  to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.

Job aborted due to stage failure ... : 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
.....
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

When doing `lsof -p <PID>` for the java process that runs that executor I can see tons(up to 90K) of TCP connections from the host server in the Kafka Brokers:

`host:portXXX->kafkabroker1:XmlIpcRegSvc (ESTABLISHED)`

`host:portYYY->kafkabroker2:XmlIpcRegSvc (ESTABLISHED)`

`host:portZZZ->kafkabroker3:XmlIpcRegSvc (ESTABLISHED)`

I tried reducing the number of executor cores from 8 to 6 but there was not a single difference in the number of open files(still it was reaching 150K) and then kept failing.

The libraries to connect to Kafka from Spark Streaming are:

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.kafkaproducer
```

The code:

```
foreachRDD{
   get kafkaProducer
   do some work on each RDD...
   foreach( record => {
      kafkaProducer.send(record._1,record._2)
   }
  kafkaProducer.close()
}
```

Comment: what library are you using to connect to Kafka from Spark? can you show us some code?

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789621/2796894

Comment: Yes but I think it is more of a matter that the Kafka connections created from the Kafka Producer should have been closing at the first place and not remaining open - needing more than 90K ESTABLISHED connections to the Kafka brokers sounds excessive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a schoolboy error. This very well explained [article](https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html) helped fixing the issue. The kafka producer was not closing the connections so we used the broadcast and lazy evaluation technique which solved the issue.