# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached - Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have updated to Spring boot 2.4.1 from 2.3.3.RELEASE, I am getting following exception in my production server logs after couple of days... I did not see this problem in 2.3.3.RELEASE and earlier. Can anybody please help in identifying why this issue might occur:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1583)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.BoundedElasticScheduler.start(BoundedElasticScheduler.java:175)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(Schedulers.java:498)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(Schedulers.java:454)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Comment: Thanks @JérémieB for the response. I have upgraded to latest version of Spring boot 2.4.2 release and I am unable to reproduce this issue anymore.