# What are the parameters to be checked in JMeter and in a Linux VM before proceeding with a 10K VUser JMeter test?

Tags: linux, testing, jmeter, out-of-memory

Tried to run a test in Non-GUI mode with 10K VUsers on a single Linux VM. Found the following error :

> Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new
> native thread (12116 threads running, rlimit (soft/hard)

The Heap Argument in JMeter has been set to 32GB. Yet there has been no improvement. I would like to know the arguments or the parameters to be checked in the Linux VM as well as JMeter before proceeding with the 10K VUser test. RAM of the machine = 65GB. Could someone help me with this please?

Thank You.

Comment: Could this be of any help to you? [JMeter SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error means that JMeter is trying to create a new [native (Linux) thread](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370047&seqNum=3) and Linux doesn't allow the thread creation as you reached the maximum number of threads.

If you have a [superuser-level access](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-login-as-super-user/) to the Linux box you can ramp-up the maximum number of threads, see [ulimit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command to determine the limits and [/proc/sys/kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html) documentation with regards to how to increase them.

If you don't have possibility to log in as root - the only solution would be getting one more machine (you may need more than one) and [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)