# AMQ222082: error on connection failure check: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, out-of-memory, activemq-artemis

I have an application deployed on WildFly, and I use the domain mode.  The VM used for deployment is full saturation when I checked the log I found the size of the server log file so big (approximately 25G). When I checked the log I found this warning is repeated:

```
2023-01-05 09:55:15,693 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (activemq-failure-check-thread) AMQ222082: error on connection failure check: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.onAddedTaskIfNotRunning(ProcessorBase.java:205)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.task(ProcessorBase.java:193)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.execute(OrderedExecutor.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$FailureCheckAndFlushThread.run(RemotingServiceImpl.java:709)
```

Can anyone here helps with this problem? I don't know I think that is due to the heap memory, but here I'm in the prod profile so what do you think?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Comment: You might be facing low OS memory condition and/or OS limit on max number of open files or tasks/threads. I recommend reading through the link posted above by Justin. This can help too: https://www.baeldung.com/java-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Comment: I am investigating in root cause , we are using managed domain to setup wildfly . I would to ask here if in this mode of setup wildfly the use of activemq for messaging is to communicate with the other hosts ???

Comment: WildFly does not use ActiveMQ Artemis to communicate with other hosts in any configuration.